# Show the point-set map is open and connected.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, connectedness

The definition of open map is as follows:

A point-set map $\varphi: X \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$ is called open when its graph $$\mbox{graph} (\varphi)=\{(x,y) \in X \times X : y \in \varphi(x), \forall x \in X\} $$ is an open set in $X \times X$, and $\varphi (x)$ is connected for all $x \in X$

I can not prove that:

Given $\varphi$ point-set map open, and an open set $C \subseteq X$, if $C$ is connected then $\varphi(C)$ is open and connected.

As $C \times C$ is open in $X \times X$, I tried to show that $\varphi(C)$ is an open relative. I did not have success.

Comment: What do you mean by $\varphi (C)$? Is it $\bigcup_{x \in C} \varphi(x)$?

Comment: Yes , we Consider that image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note que podemos escrever $\varphi(x)$ = graph $(\varphi) \cap \{x\} \times X $ que é um conjunto aberto. Assim sendo, como $\varphi(C) = \bigcup_{x \in C} \varphi(x)$ é uma união de abertos, segue que $\varphi(C)$ é aberto.

Suponha, por absurdo, que $\varphi(C)=Y$ não é conexo. Portanto existem abertos disjuntos $A$ e $B$ não vazios tais que $Y=A \cup B$. É claro que, $\varphi^{-1}(A) = \{ x \in C ; \varphi(x) \subseteq A\}$ e $\varphi^{-1}(B) = \{ x \in C ; \varphi(x) \subseteq B \}$ são não vazios (caso contrário $C=B, C=A, \; \mbox{ou} \; C=\varnothing$) e a união é todo o conjunto $C$. Vamos mostrar que $\varphi^{-1}(A)$ e $\varphi^{-1}(B)$ são disjuntos. Novamente por contradição, suponha que exista $x \in C$ tal que $x \in \varphi^{-1}(A) \cap C$ e $x \in \varphi^{-1}(B) \cap C$. Como $A$ e $B$ são disjuntos, então $\varphi(x)$ é não conexo, pois $\varphi(x) \in A$ e $\varphi(x) \in B$ que são disjuntos. Contradição, pois por definição de aplicação aberta, temos que $\varphi(x)$ é conexo $\forall x \in X$. Segue que $C= \varphi^{-1}(A) \cup \varphi^{-1}(B)$ uma união disjunta e não vazia, o que contraria o fato de $C$ ser conexo. Então $\varphi(C)$ é conexo.